Change text color of Android notification action
I'm trying to have an action on my notification with red background and white text.
I've tried:
  endString.setSpan(
        ForegroundColorSpan(
            ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.red)
        ), 0, endString.length,
        Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE
    )

But this changes the background color of the action to red while the text color itself is black.
I've also tried:
       endString.setSpan(
       BackgroundColorSpan(
           ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.red)
       ), 0, endString.length,
       Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE
   )

And while this one keeps the text color white, the red color does not fill the action area.
Is there a way to achieve a red action with white text on a notification without using a custom layout for the notification(and not using the callStyle)?
